# How can I change string output in a hierarchy tree with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, cte, recursive, string-manipulation

I have a table like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------
|  id  | description         | parent_id   |  cost
--------------------------------------------------
| 1    |  Radiology         |       NULL  | 0.00
| 2    |  Lab Tests         |       NULL  | 0.00
| 3    |  Normal Radiology  |         1   | 0.00
| 4    |  Resonance         |         1   | 100.00
| 1100 |  Cerebral Resonance|         4   | 200.00
| 1900 |  Blood Tests       |         2   | 10.00
| 2044 |  Calcium           |         2   | 50.00

---------------------------------------------------
```

I need to generate this kind of output:

```
Radiology
   -->Normal Radiology
   -->Resonance
      -->Cerebral Resonance with contrast
Lab Test
    --> Blood Test
    --> Calcium
```

I'm working on PostgreSQL. I've been trying this with a recursive CTE, but I was unable to generate what I like:

```
WITH RECURSIVE hierarchy AS (
    SELECT  id, CAST(description AS TEXT) AS parent_list
    FROM    orders
    WHERE   parent_id is null
      UNION
    SELECT  c.id,
            CAST(c2.parent_list || ' --> ' || c.description as text) as parent_list
    FROM orders c
    INNER JOIN hierarchy c2 ON c.parent_id = c2.id )

SELECT  id, parent_list
FROM     hierarchy
GROUP BY id, parent_list
ORDER BY parent_list;
```

That recursive CTE produces the following nondesirable output:

```
Radiology
Radiology--> Normal Radiology
Radiology--> Resonance
Radiology--> Resonance --> Cerebral Resonance with contrast
Lab Test
Lab Test --> Blood Test
Lab Test --> Calcium
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use somethinng like this

> ```
> CREATE TABLE orders (
>   "id" INTEGER,
>   "description" VARCHAR(18),
>   "parent_id" VARCHAR(4),
>   "cost" DECIMAL(8,2)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO orders
>   ("id", "description", "parent_id", "cost")
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'Radiology', NULL, '0.00'),
>   ('2', 'Lab Tests', NULL, '0.00'),
>   ('3', 'Normal Radiology', '1', '0.00'),
>   ('4', 'Resonance', '1', '100.00'),
>   ('1100', 'Cerebral Resonance', '4', '200.00'),
>   ('1900', 'Blood Tests', '2', '10.00'),
>   ('2044', 'Calcium', '2', '50.00');
> ```

> ```
> WITH RECURSIVE hierarchy AS (
>     SELECT  id, 1 AS rown, CAST(description AS TEXT) AS parent_list, id as parent
>     FROM    orders
>     WHERE   parent_id is null
>     UNION  
>     SELECT  c.id
>     ,rown + 1 as rown
>     ,CAST(repeat('    ', rown) || ' --> ' || c.description as text) as parent_list
>     ,parent
>     FROM orders c
>     INNER JOIN hierarchy c2 ON CAST(c.parent_id AS INTEGER) = c2.id )
> SELECT id,parent_list FROM hierarchy
> ORDER BY parent DESC,rown
> ```
>
> ```
>   id | parent_list                    
> ---: | :------------------------------
>    2 | Lab Tests                      
> 1900 |      --> Blood Tests           
> 2044 |      --> Calcium               
>    1 | Radiology                      
>    4 |      --> Resonance             
>    3 |      --> Normal Radiology      
> 1100 |          --> Cerebral Resonance
> ```

> ```
> WITH RECURSIVE hierarchy AS (
>     SELECT  id, CAST(description AS TEXT) AS parent_list, 1 AS rown, id as parent
>     FROM    orders
>     WHERE   parent_id is null
>     UNION  
>     SELECT  c.id
>     ,CAST(c2.parent_list || ' --> ' || c.description as text) as parent_list
>     ,rown + 1 as rwon
>     ,parent
>     FROM orders c
>     INNER JOIN hierarchy c2 ON CAST(c.parent_id AS INTEGER) = c2.id )
> SELECT  id, parent_list
> FROM    hierarchy
> GROUP BY id, parent_list
> ORDER BY parent_list;
> ```
>
> ```
>   id | parent_list                                   
> ---: | :---------------------------------------------
>    2 | Lab Tests                                     
> 1900 | Lab Tests --> Blood Tests                     
> 2044 | Lab Tests --> Calcium                         
>    1 | Radiology                                     
>    3 | Radiology --> Normal Radiology                
>    4 | Radiology --> Resonance                       
> 1100 | Radiology --> Resonance --> Cerebral Resonance
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1c711a915ba9aa99b866064c65964468)*

Comment: Thank you, very nice solution.

Comment: I would like to ask you a different question, how can I group this by parent_id?

Comment: please ask a new question and try to make a resuklt that you want. run a SELECT * FROM hierachy and see what columns you have, see if you can add information to Group by , for example parentid has 1 or 2 thtat us the id from the parent for all child rows, ths you can use but for mich complex SELECT i have to know which result you want, more complex more column you need

Comment: Thank you for your comments.